# How to copy a VSTS artifact to a Azure Storage account container folder?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azcopy

I have a VSTS release pipeline in which I need to copy the build artifact to a storage account blob container.
This is pretty easy with the Azure File Copy task, but the difficulty seems in the need to specify a folder in the container to copy the file to.

I tried extending the container name, but that (obviously) doesn't work. Rewriting the destination in the "additional arguments" section neither. Looking at the source of the task I cannot find anything in that direction, so I'm wondering whether it is even possible.

Any idea on how to do this using the build task? 
Or do I need to use Powershell for this?

Comment: **What** is the difficulty? Is the command failing? Azure File Copy is the correct approach, but you need to provide more details on what isn't working for you.

Comment: Typically you configure Azure subscription, storage account and container. Then the copy will be done to the root of that "container". The issue is I cannot find a way to specify how to copy to "container/folder". Do I need to specify some additional argument? Do you have an example on how to do this?

Comment: When you specify "Blob" as the destination, a text entry box appears for the container name.

Comment: yes, correct, but you cannot enter "containername/folder" in there (it fails on execution), just a containername. I like to upload my artifact to some folder in the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the folder (e.g. **A**) in another folder (**R**), then specify **R** folder path in Source box of **Azure File Copy task**, then the folder **A** will be in container.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! The folder structure is copied from the source! So by just adding this folder to the build artifacts drop, it works. Would be nice though to have the option to specify a target folder in the Azure File Copy task. Thanks again.